# How can I work against two different versions of a web service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, c#-5.0

My project is a consumer for a 3rd party web service (old school web service vs. WCF service), and it has two versions, the "sandbox" (staging), and prod services. The APIs on these services are almost identical, and I am looking for a way to cleanly switch between the two versions, preferably without using conditional compilation.

I instinctively rushed off and extracted an interface from the client generated by Visual Studio's "Add web reference", i.e. `AgentImport` but that class is not partial, so I can't make it derive from the interface, or from any other superclass. I already have the creation of `AgentImport` instances nicely encapsulated in an abstract base for all my clients of `AgentImport`, but without using more risky compiler directives, how can I switch between v1 and v2 of `AgentImport`?

Some code:

```
using Clients.PrivateProperty.AgencyServicesApiService;

namespace Client.PrivateProperty
{
    public abstract class PrivPropFacilityBase
    {
        protected static AgentImport Client;

        protected PrivPropFacilityBase()
        {
            Client = new AgentImport();
            Client.Timeout = 10000;
        }

        protected virtual AgentImport GetClient()
        {
            return new AgentImport();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding service references instead of web references, as advised in comments below, to at least get access to partial classes, but when I add the first service reference, for the production service, and extract an interface from the auto-generated SOAP client, i.e. `IAsapiClient`, that interface references objects declared in other auto-generated classes, in the same namespace as the client, e.g. `SecurityToken`:

```
void UpdateUniqueAgentID(string PrivatePropertyAgentId, string AgentId, AgencyServicesApiService.SecurityToken Token);
```

If I add the second service reference, for the staging service, that second auto-generated SOAP client references objects in its own namespace, e.g. now it uses `AgencyServicesApiSandbox.SecurityToken`, so my compiler tells me that it doesn't implement the interface I extracted the first time. I am then left with the messy business of having to extract an new interface for each object that the main interface, `IAsapiClient`, references, so that this main interface only uses the extracted contracts, not actual class names.

In pursuing the above< I have reached the conclusion that my only feasible, and lowest risk, way forward is to use two client projects, one specifically for the production service, and one for the staging service. Then, at execution time, I only need to worry about dynamically choosing between two well known, i.e. not auto-generated, client objects.

Comment: Try Add Service Reference instead of Add Web Reference. You have more options for the generated classes and I'm pretty sure it will give you partial classes. "Add Web Reference" is there to support older .NET 2.0 projects.

Comment: Thank you @KeithPayne, service references to indeed have `partial`, but now my problem is that when I extract an interface from one auto-generated proxy, that interface uses the namespace of that proxy, so I can't make the second proxy derive from that single interface anyway. Looks like something of a dead-end for now.

Comment: This is puzzling. You haven't described something that cannot be done. There's no particular reason why two classes cannot implement the same interface, regardless of namespace, unless the two classes reside in different assemblies (projects) and there is a circular dependency.